# trying to plot a still semi visable image over a matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have an animation produced with code written in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim((0,512))
ax.set_ylim((0,512))

im=ax.imshow(data[0,:,:]) 
def init ():
    im.set_data(data[0,:,:])
    return(im,)
def animate(i):
    data_slice=data[i,:,:]
    im.set_data(data_slice)
    return(im,)


ani.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=240,interval=100)
```

I can't figure out how to plot the first frame over it while making it semi see-through and keeping the animation playing in the background. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two images, one that stays on top, and another one that is modified by `animate()`:

```
# create dummy data
data = np.random.random(size=(240,512,512))
# load an image in first frame of data
temp = plt.imread('./stinkbug.png')
data[0,:,:] = 0.5
data[0,:375,:500] = temp[::-1,::-1,0]


fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim((0,512))
ax.set_ylim((0,512))

top_img = ax.imshow(data[0,:,:], zorder=10, alpha=0.5, cmap='gray')
bottom_img = ax.imshow(data[1,:,:], zorder=1, cmap='viridis')

def init():
    top_img.set_data(data[0,:,:])
    bottom_img.set_data(data[1,:,:])
    return (top_img, bottom_img)
def animate(i):
    data_slice=data[i,:,:]
    bottom_img.set_data(data_slice)
    return (bottom_img,)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=range(1,240),interval=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]